# Firefox Extension: Get Response of a XHR POST Request

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

i'm playing around with Firefox Addons and need some help. How can i get the response of a XHR Post Request? I only wanna get only the JSON Result.

Can somebody kick me in the right way please?